# TableView in TabView , Exception caught, wrong Appdelegate?

Tags: uitableview, uitabbar

I´m trying to implement my tableview that I made earlier into a new tabview-based application i just made and all build and compile, but when i choose the tab for my *imported* tableview it crashes with the following error:

```
[Session started at 2011-04-23 00:55:14 +0200.]
2011-04-23 00:55:16.361 EXOtab[1123:207] -[EXOtabAppDelegate larms]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f2b4e0
```

The object larms Is defined in my headerfile for parsing data for my tableview.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface XMLAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

UIWindow *window;
UINavigationController *navigationController;

NSMutableArray *larms;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *larms;

 - (void)loadXML;

@end
```

I dont know if I´m missing to inport any of my headerfiles from my tableview´s datamodel or if I´m having a bad referens when calling for it. ofcourse it works fine if I use it outside as a tableview app but not in my tab bar app.

my ViewControllers :

```
#import "EXOtabAppDelegate.h"
#import "EXOtabViewController.h"
#import "users.h"
#import "info.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"  // My Tableview

 @implementation EXOtabAppDelegate

 @synthesize window;
 @synthesize viewController;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

UIViewController *vc1 = [[info alloc] init];
UIViewController *vc2 = [[users alloc] init];
UIViewController *vc3 = [[RootViewController alloc] init];

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, vc3, nil];

[vc1 release];
[vc2 release];
[vc3 release];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

[window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
[tabBarController release];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

any ideas? And let me know if u need to see any more code

//reg: mandelmassa

I have some more code to show:

```
  //RootViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


if (_refreshHeaderView == nil) {

    EGORefreshTableHeaderView *view = [[EGORefreshTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - self.tableView.bounds.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height)];
    view.delegate = self;
    [self.tableView addSubview:view];
    _refreshHeaderView = view;
    [view release];

}

//  update the last update date
[_refreshHeaderView refreshLastUpdatedDate];

    //this is where the app crashes!
appDelegate = (XMLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.title = @"Larm";

}


   //RootViewController.h
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import "EGORefreshTableHeaderView.h"

  @class XMLAppDelegate, LarmDetail;

  @interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <EGORefreshTableHeaderDelegate,     UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

XMLAppDelegate *appDelegate;
LarmDetail *ldvController;

EGORefreshTableHeaderView *_refreshHeaderView;

BOOL _reloading;


 }


- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource;
- (void)doneLoadingTableViewData;

@end

//XMLAppDelegate.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface XMLAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

UIWindow *window;
UINavigationController *navigationController;

NSMutableArray *larms;
 }

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *larms;

- (void)loadXML;

@end


//XMLAppDelegate.m
#import "XMLAppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "XMLParser.h"

 @implementation XMLAppDelegate

 @synthesize window;
 @synthesize navigationController, larms;


  -(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

[self loadXML]; //egen function för att ladda data

// Configure and show the window
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
 }

 - (void)loadXML{

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://192.168.1.90/EXOxml.php?nAlarms=2"];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:    url];

//Initialize the delegate.
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

//Set delegate
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

//Start parsing the XML file.
BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

if(success)
    NSLog(@"Data loaded");
else
    NSLog(@"Data fail!!!");


 }


 - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
// Save data if appropriate
 }


 - (void)dealloc {
[larms release];
[navigationController release];
[window release];
[super dealloc];
 }

@end
```

Can any1 see why my app is casting an error?

reg Mandel

```
(XMLAppdelegate)
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface XMLAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

UIWindow *window;
UINavigationController *navigationController;

NSMutableArray *larms;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *larms;

 - (void)loadXML;

 @end
```

(XMLAppDelegate.m)

```
   #import "XMLAppDelegate.h"
   #import "RootViewController.h"
   #import "XMLParser.h"

   @implementation XMLAppDelegate

   @synthesize window;
   @synthesize navigationController, larms;


  -(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

[self loadXML]; own function to load data

// Configure and show the window
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
  }

    - (void)loadXML{

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/somefile.php?nAlarms=2"];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:    url];

//Initialize the delegate.
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

//Set delegate
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

//Start parsing the XML file.
BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

if(success)
    NSLog(@"No Errors");
else
    NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");


  }


 - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
// Save data if appropriate
}


- (void)dealloc {
[larms release];
[navigationController release];
[window release];
[super dealloc];
 }

 @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes `XMLAppDelegate` and `EXOtabAppDelegate` both implement the `UIApplicationDelegate`protocol. **You should not have more than one UIApplicationDelegate per application.**

Your application delegate is set in your main nib file (typically "MainWindow.xib"). You should have connected the File's Owner (which is the `UIApplication` object)'s "delegate" outlet to the `UIApplicationDelegate` object in the the .xib file, and the class of the `UIApplicationDelegate` is set to your app's `UIApplicationDelegate` subclass, either `XMLAppDelegate` or `EXOtabAppDelegate`.

Since your `XMLAppDelegate` has a `larms`property and your `EXOtabAppDelegate` does not have one, I guess your application delegate is actually set to `EXOtabAppDelegate` in your main nib file.

If `EXOtabAppDelegate` is your application delegate, you can not do this:

```
appDelegate = (XMLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: ...yes my property is synthesize:ed but the error says that the tab:bar appdelegate is missing it..not the model interface for creating the data for tableview?  that should be XMLAppDelegate / [EXOtabAppDelegate larms]:  something goes wrong / mandel

Comment: @mandelmassa You should not have more than one UIApplicationDelegate per application. Which one is it, EXOtabAppDelegate or XMLAppDelegate?

Comment: EXOtabAppDelegate is only used for my navigation with tabs, XMLAppDelegate is used to parse/store data for my tableview, Bu tI guess I´m messing things up abit when importing an already tableviewbased application into a tabbased view, not getting further though. If i use the tableview outside tabbars it works fine :(

Comment: @mandelmassa You can only have one application delegate. If it is your EXOtabAppDelegate, you can not do this: `appDelegate = (XMLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

Comment: ok, so when I made my UItableview application I hade my appDelegate = (XMLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; set.. And when i created my tab-bar application and push it into the view i mess things up with delegation since I have my old settings set when it was not  used in a tabbarview? I´m a bit confused yet but I see what your getting at. Putting my tableview into this made me have to learn new stuff again. So do you have any ideas what I need to change to make it work? Do I need to implement my code for XMLdata in XMLAppDelegate into my EXOtabAppDelegate instead?

Comment: @mandelmassa If I understood right, XMLAppDelegate was the application delegate of a previous application you did. The application delegate of your current application is EXOtabAppDelegate. I think you should not use XMLAppDelegate at all in your current application.

Comment: Ok. i see..so what you say is that (see added code above ..last parts) I should move those functions and declarations into my new delegate and declare appDelegate = (EXOtabAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  instead? :) ?

Comment: @mandelmassa Yes, you can do `appDelegate = (EXOtabAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` if your application delegate class is set to EXOtabAppDelegate in your main nib file

Comment: @albertamg  , (i gotta ask) I suppose I have to move my methods and declare NSMutableArray *larms in my new delgate EXOtabAppDelegate to make it work from my tableview?

Comment: @mandelmassa you have a number of options when it comes to code organization: the table view controller, a custom class or even your EXOtabAppDelegate (so yes, it's an option).